# For Each loop loops twice and it shouldn't in VB code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, foreach

I have a For Each loop that should loop one time for each file added to a FileUpload control.  If I add 1 file or 10 files it will loop twice for each file, and I can't figure out why.

In production inside of the loop I call 4 different functions.  For trouble shooting I've commented out all but one of these functions.  The `SendScript_SaveInfoToDatabase(fileName)` function only calls a stored procedure which writes to the database.  It does nothing else.

Here is the loop in question.  You can see I've commented out some of the unnecessary stuff.

```
Protected Sub PostFiles()

 For Each postedFile As HttpPostedFile In fuAttachment.PostedFiles
    Dim fileName As String = Session("LoggedInRep").ToString() & "_" & Now().ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "_" & Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName)
    postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/scripts/") & fileName)

    SendScript_SaveInfoToDatabase(fileName)
    'SendScript_SendEmail(fileName)
    'SendScript_SendText(fileName)
    'SendScript_SendFax(fileName)
    'Response.Write("inner1-" & postedFile.FileName.Count.ToString & "<BR>")

Next

'Response.Write("OutterLoop1-" & "<BR>")

'btn_submit.Enabled = True
'lblSuccess.Text = lblSuccess.Text & "<BR>" & String.Format("{0} files have been uploaded successfully.", fuAttachment.PostedFiles.Count)

End Sub
```

A button fires the above sub, nothing too exciting.... check it out:

```
Protected Sub UploadMultipleFiles(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_submit.Click

    btn_submit.Enabled = False

    PostFiles()

End Sub
```

Comment: is PostFiles() called in page load  by any chance?

Comment: Connect a debugger and put a breakpoint on the entry point to PostFiles. When the breakpoint is hit, look at the call stack to see what is causing the duplicate call. If you can't do the debugger, perhaps write the call stack to the response (you could intentionally throw and then catch the exception to get to the call stack in a quick and dirty method).

Comment: @MartinSoles - I actually can't debug on this site.  I am editing remotely via ftp in VS 2015 and the debug doesn't work.  I'm used to programming on a corporate network, and suspect the change in environment is my issue.  Although not related to this post, do you know how I can change my setup to be able to debug?  I typically have local copy of the site and once I'm happy with a page I push it to the production version.  I don't know how to accomplish that with how I have things set up.  Thought's if possible?

Comment: I'm not sure about remote debugging via ftp. The VS remote debugger opens a port to do the communication. Since running a debugger is out of the question, try dumping the call stack to the response (as inline comments to not dirty up the layout) or a log file (so as to not expose the call stack to anyone that does a "View Source" in their browser) at the start of the PostFiles method.